# How do I define an enum variable contained in a class

Tags: c++, enums

A quick C++ question (I think). I have a class that contains a public enum variable in its header file:

```
class TritonRackController {
    public:
          enum CurrentMode {MODE_COMBI, MODE_PGM, MODE_MULTI};
    // etc.
};
```

Then, when using an object of this class I need to set a variable to the CurrentMode value:

```
TritonRackController* tritonRackController = new TritonRackController();
TritonRackController::CurrentMode tritonMode = tritonRackController->CurrentMode;
// compile error on line above: Invalid use of 'enum TritonRackController::CurrentMode
```

I thought this would compile OK, but am confused as to why it doesn't. Also, I'm assuming in the enum statement, I've defined a type - is that correct?

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: I think you wan to say something like this: `TritonRackController::CurrentMode tritonMode = TritonRackController::MODE_COMBI`

Comment: You need to post all of the code, but you probably are misunderstanding what `tritonRackController->CurrentMode` means to the compiler.

Comment: Ahh worked it out guys: the enum CurrentMode was defining a type, then I've added a variable definition: CurrentMode currentMode; in the class. Then, I can access it with: TritonRackController::CurrentMode tritonMode = tritonRackController->currentMode. My problem was I was confusing the enum as a variable, when it's more like a typedef.

Comment: @Brad S. - if I was wanting to set it to eg. MODE_COMBI, your code would work - although it's not what I wanted the code to do, it's inherent in your example that I needed to treat the enum as a typedef, not a variable.

Comment: LOLs @ the downvote for the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a data member of type CurrentMode?

```
private:
   CurrentMode m_eMode;
```

then provide a public accessor

```
public:
  CurrentMode GetMode() const {return m_eMode;}
```

so then your code to set a local variable should use the GetMode() accessor:

```
   TritonRackController::CurrentMode tritonMode = tritonRackController->GetMode();
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize m_eMode in your ctor!

Comment: Thanks franji1 - yes I needed a data member, as you listed. I got the enum confused with a variable, when in fact its merely a typedef and needed a variable of that type instantiated...thanks again.